# Making $t$ a subject of equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this equation I want to make the variable $t$ a subject. Is this possible?

$$s = ut + \frac12 at^2$$

Comment: Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: What's a *subject* of an equation?

Comment: the variable that is on one side of an equation(alone), and has no repetitions on the other side @Bernard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to solve for $t$.

$$
s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}\implies\frac{1}{2}at^{2}+ut-s=0. 
$$

Hence, by the quadratic formula,

$$
t=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^{2}+2as}}{a}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much man! I'll accept after 11 minutes(I can only do after 11).